# How to customly resolve Assembly version conflict

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

CIn our .NET application we have project **A** that reference  an infrastructural project, let's call it **Infra**. Now, project **A** also references project B, which resides in a different solution, referencing another version of the Infra. The top level application, project **C**, references project **A**.

While this compiles just fine, it has another side effect - it does not copy the **Infra.dll** to the bin folder of project **C**.

I increased the verbosity of the build output, to see what exactly is the problem, and saw this:

> There was a conflict between "Infra, Version=1.1.14.9..." and "Infra,
>   Version=1.0.0.0 ...". "Infra, Version=1.1.14.9" was chosen because it
>   had a higher version.

That actually makes a lot of sense, having 2 conflicting references to the same version should try to get the higher version.  The problem is that **B** project's reference to **Infra** is not an accessible path and therefore will not be copied.

I could surly solve this issue by adding a reference form project **C** directly to **infra**, but I would prefer not to. I was wondering whether I could tell the compiler explicitly which version to use.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twy1dw1e(v=vs.110).aspx. Should put you on the right path.

Comment: Your question started with "we have project A that references Infra".  And ends with "I can solve this problem by having A reference Infra".  That makes no sense.

Comment: @HansPassant I think what he means is that `A` and `B` both reference Infra albeit with different versions and he'd like to instruct CLR which version of the two it should load when resolving the assemblies. At least that's how I understood the question. I agree the wording on the last paragraph is a bit confusing though and I may have completely got his question wrong because I don't quite understand it.

Comment: @HansPassant you are right. I will fix the question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add compile parameter to csc command using Visual Studio IDE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849637/add-compile-parameter-to-csc-command-using-visual-studio-ide)